# Mocking Response Python Unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, unicode, mocking

I'm trying to create a mock response and want to set the response.text to some unicode chars.

Here's the code:

```
class TestClass(TestCase):
    @mock.patch(self, mocked_get)
    def test_func(self):
        mocked_get.side_effect = self.mocked_get
        expected_result = [u'ssemsth']
        result = self.api.query(query_params)
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result)

def mocked_get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    class MockResponse():
        def test_result():
           res = Response()
           res.message = u'semsmth'
           return res

    # some testcondition
    mock_response = MockResponse()
    if self.api.counter == 1:
         return mock_response.test_result()
```

In the result for the response, I'm getting `[u'']`, a list with empty unicode string. I want to get `[u'semsmth']`

Any thoughts? I'm thinking I can't set the `res.message = u'semsth'` and just return that. How do I set this attribute for the Response() object i'm sending to the calling test_function

Comment: which version of python is this?

Comment: @JacobIRR it's python 2.7